# Trying to set a background image that always covers the form, but has a static/fixed aspect ratio

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing

So I've been looking around on this question quite a bit, but the results always keep coming back to either setting `BackgroundImageLayout` to "Stretch". Which, of course, doesn't do *anything* about maintaining the aspect ratio of the original image or to tutorials on how to scale a `PictureBox` or other loaded images manually while retaining the aspect ratio, but I cannot (very surprisingly to me) find anything about how to get a WinForm to manage a background image that's always centered on the window, stretched to cover it, but maintaining the same aspect ratio as the original.

I tried this:

```
public class CustomForm : Form
{
    protected Size _scale;
    protected Size _originalSize;
    protected float _aspectRatio;

    public CustomForm() : base()
    {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

    private float AspectRatio() { return this.AspectRatio(this._originalSize); }
    private float AspectRatio(int width, int height) { return (float)width / height; }
    private float AspectRatio(Size value) { return this.AspectRatio(value.Width, value.Height); }

    protected override void OnBackgroundImageChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        this._originalSize = new Size(this.BackgroundImage.Width, this.BackgroundImage.Height);
        this._aspectRatio = this.AspectRatio(this._originalSize);
        base.OnBackgroundImageChanged(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.BackgroundImage == null) base.OnPaintBackground(e);
        else
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), ClientRectangle);

            int x = (this._scale.Width > this.Width) ? (int)Math.Round((this._scale.Width - this.Width) / 2.0) : 0;
            int y = (this._scale.Height > this.Height) ? (int)Math.Round((this._scale.Height - this.Height) / 2.0) : 0;

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.BackgroundImage, new Rectangle(x, y, this._scale.Width, this._scale.Height));
        }
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if ( this._aspectRatio > this.AspectRatio(this.Size))
        {
            this._scale.Width = this.Width;
            this._scale.Height = (int)(this.Width / this._aspectRatio);
        }
        else
        {
            this._scale.Height = this.Height;
            this._scale.Width = (int)(this.Height * this._aspectRatio);
        }
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
    }
}
```

But all it does is fix the image in the top-left corner of the form at it's basic dimensions, regardless of how the form is (re)sized...

Can someone please point me in the direction of a proper solution, or to what I've got / done wrong thus far?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after a bunch more research, and with some bodging, I finally got this sorted out! Posting this here for anyone who may come looking for it in the future!

```
public class CustomForm : Form
{
    protected Size _scale;
    protected Size _originalSize;

    public CustomForm() : base()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnBackgroundImageChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        this._originalSize = new Size(this.BackgroundImage.Width, this.BackgroundImage.Height);
        base.OnBackgroundImageChanged(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((BackgroundImage != null) && (BackgroundImageLayout == ImageLayout.None))
        {
            Point p = new Point(
                            (int)((this.Width - this._scale.Width) / 2),
                            (int)((this.Height - this._scale.Height) / 2)
                          );

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.BackgroundImage, new Rectangle(p, this._scale));
        }
        else
            base.OnPaintBackground(e);
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((BackgroundImage != null) && (BackgroundImageLayout == ImageLayout.None))
        {
            float rX = (float) this.Width / this._originalSize.Width;
            float rY = (float) this.Height / this._originalSize.Height;
            float r = (rX < rY) ? rY : rX;

            this._scale.Height = (int)(this._originalSize.Height * r);
            this._scale.Width = (int)(this._originalSize.Width * r);
        }
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this._originalSize = new Size(0, 0);
        this._scale = new Size(0, 0);

        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // CustomForm
        // 
        this.Name = "CustomForm";
        this.DoubleBuffered = true; // minimizes "flicker" when resizing
        this.ResizeRedraw = true; // forces a full redraw when resized!
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
}
```